# How to get array from form in JS or Mootools to send it than to PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, json, mootools

[IMAGE OF FORM](http:////habrastorage.org/files/c93/c6b/e44/c93c6be4435e463487fa5cd0ebf1c980.jpg)

HTML:

```
<select name="birthdate[day]" id="birthdate-day" class="date_class">
    <option value="0"> </option>
     .....
</select>
<select name="birthdate[month]" id="birthdate-month" class="date_class">
    <option value="0"></option>
    ..........
</select>
<select name="birthdate[year]" id="birthdate-year" class="date_class">
    <option value="0"> </option>
    <option value="2015">2015</option>
     ....
</select>
```

I tried to get data this way, but it didn't works:

```
var birthdate = $contactForm.getElement('select[name="birthdate"]').getProperty('value');
```

How to get array from form in JS or Mootools to send it than to PHP? Will be send data to PHP in JSON format.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert form data to JS object with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/convert-form-data-to-js-object-with-jquery)

Comment: @copeg need mootools

Comment: Do you want the selected value of that `select` element`or a array with all selected values of the form's selects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your selector.  You are giving a partial `name`, but with the syntax you are using it expects the complete `name`.

So try something like:

```
var birthdate = $contactForm.getElement('select[name^="birthdate"]').getProperty('value');
```

However this is only going to get you the first element that matches.

So with MooTools, you could do something like:

```
$$('select[name^=birthdate]')
```

Or in JS:

```
document.querySelectorAll('select[name^=birthdate]')
```

Hope that helps